# Simplification of algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify this algebra expression.

$$\sqrt{x^2+9}(\frac{4}{3})\sqrt{4x-3}\cdot4+(4x-3)^{\frac{3}{2}}(\frac{1}{2})\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}(2x)$$

My attempts,

$=\frac{16}{3}\sqrt{x^2+9}\sqrt{4x-3}+\frac{x(4x-3)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$

$=(x^2-9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{4x-3}\left [ \frac{16}{3}\cdot(x^2+9)^{-1}+x(4x-3)^3 \right ]$

I'm stuck here. The given answer is $\frac{\sqrt{4x-3}(28x^2-9x+144)}{3\sqrt{x^2+9}}$.

Answer (score 2):

In a few systematic steps; coefficients in front:
$$\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{x^2+9}\sqrt{4x-3}\cdot4+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}(4x-3)^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\color{red}{2}x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$
Simplify (red) and take out the factor $\tfrac{\sqrt{4x-3}}{3\sqrt{x^2+9}}$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{4x-3}}{3\sqrt{x^2+9}}\Bigl(4\left(x^2+9\right)\cdot4+3x(4x-3)\Bigr)$$
Simplify the expression between brackets:
$$\frac{\sqrt{4x-3}}{3\sqrt{x^2+9}}\Bigl(28x^2-9x+144\Bigr)$$

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors in your expression. The correct one is

$$\frac{16}{3}\sqrt{x^2+9}\sqrt{4x-3}+\frac{x(4x-3)^\frac{3}{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+9}} = (x^2+9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{4x-3}\left[\frac{16}{3}(x^2+9)+x(4x-3)\right], $$

and this gives the correct result. The point is that when you group $(x^2+9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\sqrt{4x-3}$ you have to *subtract* $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ respectively from the powers of $x^2+9$ and $4x-3$ you are dividing from.

Comment: It looks like you meant to extract the factor $(x^2 \color{red}{+} 9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt -

$\frac{16}{3}\sqrt{x^2+9}\sqrt{4x-3}+\frac{x(4x-3)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$

$=(x^2-9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{4x-3}\left [ \frac{16}{3}\cdot(x^2+9)^{-1}+x(4x-3)^3 \right ]$

If I let you are taking $(x^2-9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{4x-3}$ common then first thing is no term containing $(x^2-9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. It is $(x^2+9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Second thing if I multiply $(x^2+9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ with $(x^2+9)^{-1}$. Its become $(x^2+9)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

Similarly mistake with other term.

So correct way is -

$\frac{16}{3}\sqrt{x^2+9}\sqrt{4x-3}+\frac{x(4x-3)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$

$=(x^2+9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{4x-3}\left [ \frac{16}{3}\cdot(x^2+9)+x(4x-3)\right ]$